# How to put ViewPager on top of listview?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

How can i put **ViewPager** on the top of **ListView** as in **The-Verge Android Application** ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that was solved by adding the view pager view to the header of the list 
`listview.addHeaderView(viewpager)`

Answer (score 2):

today is your lucky day......https://www.dropbox.com/s/5bxkof1atwxqbsk/viewpagersadasd_2.rar

its the link to the simple project that i created,if you find my answer useful,accept it as the answer